# Real number of permutations to the "Drive You Nuts" puzzle?

Tags: probability, combinatorics, permutations

Over at [this post on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2600924/generating-all-unique-combinations-for-drive-ya-nuts-puzzle) user Yuval wrote a partial python program to brute-force the single solution for the drive ya nuts puzzle.

[image: What are the actual number of permutations to the "Drive You Nuts" puzzle]

The puzzle consists of 7 hexagons with the numbers 1-6 on them, and all pieces must be aligned so that each number is adjacent to the same number on the next piece. There is only one valid solution.

The OP contends that

> The puzzle has `~1.4G` non-unique possibilities: you have `7!` options
>   to sort the pieces by order (for example, `center=0`, `top=1`,
>   continuing in clockwise order...). After you sorted the pieces, you
>   can rotate each piece in 6 ways (each piece is a hexagon), so you get
>   `6**7` possible rotations for a given permutation of the 7 pieces.
>   Totalling: `7!*(6**7)=~1.4G` possibilities.

So my question is, are there really `7!*(6**7)=~1.4 billion` permutations to this puzzle? Can someone better explain to me how there aren't only 6**7=279,936 permutations?

Comment: $6^7$ combinations assumes that each hexagon is left in one position throughout. We have $7!$ ways to arrange the hexagons and in each arrangement there are $6^7$ possible settings.

Comment: Holy cow, you're right.

Comment: Note that if we count there being only one solution (rather than $6$ solutions) then we should treat rotations as the same, and you should actually get $7!6^6$ positions.

Comment: The solution space can be reduced considerably. There are seven possibilities for the middle hexagon, and the orientation of this doesn't matter. The numbers on the central hexagon define the outside places. There are $6!$ ways of organising the outer hexagons, and if you match the interface with the central hexagon you have only one orientation of each worth checking.

Answer (score 4):

There are far far far fewer possibilities that you have to consider to brute force it.

- Pick one piece for the centre ($7$ options)
- Orient it with the $1$ pointing up
- Pick an order for the other $6$ pieces ($6!$ options)
- Orient each one to match the centre
- Check whether they match around the ring

That's $7! = 5040$ cases. But actually the checks around the ring can be done while generating the permutation around the ring, allowing a lot of short-circuiting.