# How many essentially different Drive Ya Nuts Puzzles exist?

Tags: combinatorics, polya-counting-theory

In the [Drive Ya Nuts](https://www.cs.brandeis.edu/~storer/JimPuzzles/MATCH/DriveYaNuts/DriveYaNutsPhoto.jpg) puzzle, we are given $7$ hexagonal nuts, whose edges have been numbered from $1$ to $6$.  Each nut uses all $6$ numbers.  The aim of the puzzle is to place all the nuts in a hexagonal grid, so that touch sides are numbered the same.  In the marketed puzzle, there is a unique solution, provided that solutions arising from rotations of the entires grid are regarded as identical.  (This is easy to confirm.  There are only $7$ ways to place the nuts in the grid, and since rotations don't matter, we can assume the central hexagon has the $1$ on the north.  There is then only one possible orientation for each of the outer hexagons, and we just have to check if they lead to a solution.)

I wonder how many possible puzzles of this type have the attractive property of having a unique solution.  That is, how many sets  of $7$ different numbered hexagons  give a puzzle with a unique solution?  We can represent a hexagon by listing it numbers in clockwise order.  Since rotating a nut gives the same nut, we always start with the $1$.  Also, since permuting all the labels does not essentially change the puzzle, we may assume that $123456$, which I will call the "unit", for want of a better term, is always one of the nuts.

I'm confident that I can find all such essentially different sets.  We may assume that the central hexagon is the unit, oriented with $1$ on top.  Now if we look at the $6$ edges radiating out from vertices of the unit, each is constrained to have one of $4$ possible labels, or we would have a hexagon with two sides labeled the same. For the same reason, no two consecutive "spokes" can have the same label.  Brute force calculation shows there are $1144$ possible labelings.  Once we have such a labeling, each of the outer hexagons has $3$ unlabeled sides, which may be labeled in $3!$ ways, so we have $$1144\cdot6^6=53,373,464$$ positions with at least one solution.  Many of these will be relabelings of other such positions, so by generating the positions, keeping track of the ones seen, and rejecting isomorphs, I think testing them all will be quite feasible.  (Obviously, I will use backtrack rather than generating all $5040$ positions.)

My problem is relating this answer to the number of possible puzzles.  The possible number of nuts is  $5!$=120, so the possible number of nut sets is $${119\choose6}=3,470,108,187$$  However, this ignores the, fact that some of these are just relabelings of others.  We are only interested in permutations of the numbers that result in a set containing the unit.  If we pick any of the nuts, we can replace any of its labels by $1$, the next label in clockwise order by $2$, and so on.  This gives $42$ possible permutations for a given nut set.

My problem is figuring out what nut sets are invariant under which permutations.  By what has gone before, the only permutations that might leave a nut set invariant are   $6$-cycles or $5$-cycles.  My instinct is that no $5$-cycle will work, but I don't know how to prove it.  Part of what confuses me is that we have to take account of the canonical forms.  Let us apply the permutation 
$$\sigma={1\,2\,3\,4\,5\,6\choose2\,3\,4\,5\,6\,1}$$ to the hexagon $\tau=132465$.  We get successively 
$$\begin{align}\tau&=132465\\
\sigma\tau&=243516\\
\sigma^2\tau&=354321\\
\sigma^3\tau&=465132
\end{align}$$  Notice that $\sigma^3\tau$ is just a rotation of $\tau$, so $\sigma^3\tau=\tau.$

I've thought of Polya's theory of counting, of course, but I can't see how to apply it.  I feel that there is probably a simple way of attacking this problem, but I just don't see it.  Alternatively, am I making things difficult by requiring that the unit be part of the set?  Would it somehow be easier to remove this requirement?

I can of course, compute the orbits of all $5$- and $6$-cycles

Any direction or assistance will be appreciated.

**EDIT**

I can prove that no $5$-cycle leaves any nut set invariant.

The length of an orbit must divide the order of a cycle, so that the orbits of a $5$-cycle $\sigma$ have length $1$ or $5$.  If an orbit has length $1$, say $\tau=\sigma\tau$ then $\sigma$ rotates $\tau$, but this is impossible, since $\sigma$ leaves an element fixed.  It is impossible to account for all $7$ elements of the nut set using only orbits of length $5$.

Comment: In case you weren't aware, a similar question of [Real number of permutations to the "Drive You Nuts" puzzle?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3303989/real-number-of-permutations-to-the-drive-you-nuts-puzzle) was asked, and answered, here only about $3$ days ago.

Comment: @JohnOmielan Yes, that's where I became acquainted with the puzzle, but it has no bearing on what I'm asking.  Also, the $279,936$ permutations discussed there is misleading, since as I explained, only $5040$ need to be considered.

Comment: There seem to be multiple equivalence relations in play here, and I'm not sure what exactly you're trying to count. On the one hand there are solutions which use the same cogs but rearranged. (There are arguably two equivalence classes there, depending on whether it's over all arrangements or just canonical ones). Then there are isomorphisms under relabelling (and rotation?), which necessarily includes non-canonical arrangements.

Comment: @PeterTaylor Sorry, I didn't get a notice of your comment (or I overlooked it somehow.)  I'm trying to count two different things.  One is the number of sets with a unique solution, and I think I can do that by brute force.  The other, which I'm having trouble with, is the number of different nut sets, where two nut sets are the same if one is a relabeling of the other.  There are indeed multiple equivalence relations.  Two nuts are identical if one is a rotation of the other.  Two nut sets are identical if they contain the same nuts.  ...

Comment: @PeterTaylor ... Two nut sets are equivalent if one is a relabeling of the other, taking the last two sentences of the previous comment into account.  I want to determine the number of equivalence classes of nut sets.  It isn't really apposite to say that some of these are non-canonical arrangements.  I mean canonicity to apply to the solutions, not to the nut sets themselves.  I only really use canonicity in counting nut sets with a single solution, so I may have conflated these ideas in my question.

Comment: @PeterTaylor Maybe I misunderstood you.  Since we can always relabel a nut set so as to contain the unit, we only need count nut sets that contain the unit.  Is this what you meant by "canonical"?  There may, however, be more than one nut set containing the unit in a single equivalence class (at least, I don't see why it should be impossible) and that is the issue I'm struggling with.

Comment: I'm using *arrangement* as a synonym of *solution* which puts emphasis on the position and orientation of the nuts. By "canonical" I mean "having the unit nut in the centre, oriented with the 1 at the top". From a canonical solution one can derive non-canonical solutions by relabelling or by rotating the board by a multiple of 60 degrees. By rotating and relabelling one can also derive further canonical solutions, which are equivalent in some sense but probably use different nuts.

Comment: @PeterTaylor Yes, that's exactly what I mean by a solution.

Comment: The 42 relabellings are still within the realm of brute force. Normalising each of the canonical solutions to the relabelling which gives the lexicographically earliest cog set (sorting cogs within a set before comparing), I find that four cog sets have a unique solution (e.g. 123456 124653 132645 135426 153462 156243 164235) and at the other extreme two have 120 solutions each (e.g. 123456 123456 123645 126453 146253 156243 156423). There are 6901100 distinct cog sets modulo this normalisation.

Comment: @PeterTaylor Can you explain how you arrived at $6,901,100$ please?

Comment: In essence, `foreach canonical_solution { counter[min(42_relabellings(canonical_solution))]++; }`. I can post some C# code if you want, but it's not production quality.

Comment: @PeterTaylor I would certainly appreciate seeing the cod, thanks.

Comment: @PeterTaylor I don't want to nag, but I'd appreciate your posting an answer, including the code.

Comment: My apologies: I saw the comment on my phone, and forgot about it when I got back to a computer. I don't think this actually answers the question, although it might answer the question behind the question. https://gist.github.com/pjt33/54c97c5fca7e872cfb2dcd003f9b1728